# MySql - QSqlError is not caught

Tags: c++, mysql, qt

Here's my code snippet:

```
try 
{
    if ( query.exec(query_str) == false ) {
    err_desc = query.lastError().text().toStdString();
    return RET_FAIL;
    }
}
catch(QSqlError &e)
{   
    handleError(e);
}
```

I set a breakpoint inside handleError, but it seems this breakpoint was never reached when there is an error, with `err_desc` the following value:

`MySQL server has gone away QMYSQL: unable to execute query`

Why does it fail to catch the error ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because there's no error to catch.

If the query fails it return false and set a `QSqlError`, accessible via `QSqlQuery::lastError()`, but it doesn't raise an exception.

```
if ( query.exec(query_str) == false ) {
    err_desc = query.lastError().text().toStdString();
    handleError(query.lastError());
    return RET_FAIL;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I suspect you are not getting an exception when the server has gone away. 
There are other [posts on handling this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3615422/mysql-server-has-gone-away)